# In Pages editor, how can I add a droplist control so that I can add specific parameters for a Text Field?

Tags: horizon

I want to be able to add a droplist control (and have it appear) under the "Content" section when I select-to-edit a Text Field in the Pages editor.

[image: Pages Editor - A Text Field selected with empty Content controls]

My purpose for this is to add a way to specify which heading tag it should render whether its  H1, H2, or H6.

I noticed that for an Image, it does have this thing like an image browser and I basically want the same but instead it would be a droplist.

[image: Pages Editor - A Image Field selected with image browser control under the Content Section]

Is there anyone here who can help me with this one?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on a given field type you will have different editing options in Content.

From your screenshots I beleive that you are using a `Simple Text` field, if you would like to have a drop down list option to manage your content you can use a `Drop-down Menu` field type in your content item template. This will allow you to select a Sitecore item from a list.

Note that there are two types of drop-down menus that you can include in a content item template:

1. `Drop Tree` allows the user to select from a list with folders;
2. `Drop List` shows a simple list of items.

Read more [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/edit-or-reset-a-field-in-content.html).

**Please note that Horizon is no longer supported after XP 10.2 and is not included with XP 10.3, see [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/what%27s-new/deprecated-features-in-xp-10-3.html).**